# Magento 2: During creating of a custom search engine getting issue with indexer

Tags: magento2, search, advanced-search, search-engine

I have created a custom search engine to integrate with third party services to get the data instead of Elasticsearch.
After creating the custom search engine I am getting issue with indexers during running indexer command:

```
Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
There is no such engine: cognitivesearch
```

The search engine in `core_config_data` table is already set as `cognitivesearch`.

I'm not understanding what else I need to do. If anyone faced the same issue, please do let me know.

Comment: please try the below command.
php bin/magento indexer: reset
Php bin/magento indexer: reindex

Comment: Already tried that, but no luck